# For loop undefined offset error in Laravel query

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I'm trying to include a `for loop` to add where conditionals to my query and it is returning an `undefined offset 1` error on `$ProductSubCategory`. The contents of `$ProductSubCategory` is an array of strings I'd like to include as conditionals.

```
$Product = Product::select('id','ProductWorkpiece','ProductCategory','ProductName','ProductImage','ProductSubCategory')
    ->where('Status','=','1')
    ->Where(function ($query) use ($ProductSubCategory) {
        for ($i=1; $i <= $ProductSubCategory ; $i++) { 
            $Product->where('ProductSubCategory', '=', $ProductSubCategory[$i]);
        }
    })->get();
```

https://pastebin.com/uDSywsQv (Laravel Query Builder snippet)

Here is the MySQL query I would like to replicate using Laravel's query builder, how would I go about doing this?

```
SELECT 
    `id`,
    `ProductWorkpiece`,
    `ProductCategory`,
    `ProductName`,
    `ProductImage`,
    `ProductSubCategory`
FROM
    `Product`
WHERE 
    `ProductSubCategory` = 'Laser Marking Machine' OR 
    `ProductSubCategory` = 'Dot Marking Machine' OR 
    `ProductSubCategory` = 'Digital Microscope' AND 
    `Status` = '1'
```

https://pastebin.com/AMWCz32g (Desired MySQL snippet)

Comment: `$i <= $ProductSubCategory` -- change to `$i <= count($ProductSubCategory)`

Comment: Eloquent queries return a collection so you could also do `$i <= $ProductSubCategory->count()` if this is a collection.

Comment: That is really a bad solution. why don't you use `whereIn` for your code. something like : `$products = Product::whereStatus(1)->whereIn(''ProductSubCategory', $ProductSubCategory) ->get` in which `$ProductSubCategory` is an array. You can keep your code really clean in Laravel framework. Do this to avoid future headaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this `$ProductSubCategory` is not an array or does not have the index of `1`. Depending on the contents of `$ProductSubCategory` there are a few approaches you can use.

**Solution 1: $ProductSubCategory is an array of strings**

```
$Product = Product::select('id','ProductWorkpiece','ProductCategory','ProductName','ProductImage','ProductSubCategory')
    ->where('Status','=','1')
    ->whereIn('ProductSubCategory', $ProductSubCategory)
    ->get();
```

Here you can use `whereIn()` and specify the array of strings, no need to loop through anything.

**Solution 2.1: $ProductSubCategory is an object collection of records**

```
$Product = Product::select('id','ProductWorkpiece','ProductCategory','ProductName','ProductImage','ProductSubCategory')
    ->where('Status','=','1')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($ProductSubCategory) {
        foreach($ProductSubCategory as $subcategory) {
            $query->orWhere('ProductSubCategory', '=', $subcategory->name);
        }
    })->get();
```

Here we loop through each object record using `foreach` and then reference the `name` field from that object using a `orWhere` rather than `WHERE foo = bar AND foo = bar2 AND foo = bar3`

*$subcategory->name is used as placeholder, use the the field name which applies to you.*

**Note** In your version you did `function($query)` but then referenced `$Product` instead of `$query` to do your where clause.

**Edit / Update**

**Solution 2.2: $ProductSubCategory is an object collection of records**

```
$subCategories = $ProductSubCategory->only('name')->toArray();
$Product = Product::select('id','ProductWorkpiece','ProductCategory','ProductName','ProductImage','ProductSubCategory')
        ->where('Status','=','1')
        ->whereIn('ProductSubCategory', $subCategories)
        ->get();
```

This is the same as Solution 1 except we've used the collection method `only()` to retrieve only the `name` field (Change accordingly) and then converted the names `toArray()` so it can be used as part of a `whereIn` conditional. *This is untested on my side but should work in theory*

I could be more helpful knowing the contents and type of `$ProductSubCategory`.

Comment: contents and type of $ProductSubCategory is,  array ([0] = Marking [1] = Steel and many more)

Comment: The first solution should work for you.

Comment: yes its work ,thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

inside tou loop $Product is not accessible try replace by $query :

$query->where('ProductSubCategory', '=', $ProductSubCategory[$i]);